# Parse Excel file using Go on OS X

Tags: excel, go

I'm trying to read Excel file with GoLang (even not .xlsx) and by using several libraries can't have success in it. The libraries just crashes on OpenFile stage with such error:

zip: not a valid zip file

Libraries which I tried to use:
https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx
https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx2csv/

There were some others too, but they were crashed during

go get Name-of-Lib because of some Dll problems.

Any ideas? Is it because I'm trying to do in under MacOS or by some other reason?

Comment: Excelize is a library written in pure Go providing a set of functions that allow you to write to and read from XLAM / XLSM / XLSX / XLTM / XLTX files. Supports reading and writing spreadsheet documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The libraries you are trying to use [1](https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx), [2](https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx2csv/) support only newest Microsoft Excel format which is actually a zip with xml documents. Therefore you get error: `zip: not a valid zip file`. Those can be used on your MacOS, but first you need to convert the old XLS files into XLSX files. You should be able to convert them with LibreOffice in headless mode like described other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522904/how-to-open-an-excel-file-using-openoffice-and-save-as-csv), you can run a process from your code.

The other libraries are failing with "dll" errors because they must be linked against [Windows Dynamic Link Libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library). As so, they are not usable on your MacOS.

Comment: Thanks, it explains it. Is any library in Go which can work directly with XLS not XLSX? The manual process of converting one format to another one looks not really nice.

Comment: @BogdanNechyporenko Well, I don't know any, but you can ask for here, on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or on [golang-nuts mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts). Yet, I don't think that it is worth investing time to implement a library in a modern language to read old Microsoft files in a standard that was not publicly available.

Comment: Unlikely, I'm afraid: these old formats (there are several of  them despite the same extension) use Microsoft CDF as the container format and Microsoft XBIFF inside. So reading them is way harder than XLSX (a bunch of XML files in a ZIP archive)